# Saving NMEA data to file Android

Tags: android, file, gps, nmea

I need to save the NMEA strings that I receive from GPS provider. I'm searching for a safe way to save these strings, that i receive almost every second, on a file; is there a way to save block of data, for example every 5 seconds ? Is there a way to have a mechanism like databases to be sure of the writing in case of application crashing ??

My idea was to use BufferedOutputStream but I know that is not efficient to write and flush every string that i receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a concrete example in code so here is where to start. [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)
have what you're looking for and several additional options. If you have an example in code that you've tried, post it here if you'd like specific help.